# getting grunt-istanbul error: No coverage information was collected

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, qunit, istanbul

I've built a grunt setup for testing using qunit and generating coverage reports with istanbul but I can't get the storeCoverage task to complete without the error: No coverage information was collected.

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt)
{
  "use strict";

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
    connect: {
      root_server: {
        options: {
          port: 2424,
          base: 'qunit'
        },
      }
    },
    qunit: {
      all: ['qunit/test1.html']
    },
    instrument: {
      files: "testable.js",
      options: {
        lazy: true,
        basePath: "qunit/"
      }
    },
    storeCoverage: {
      options: {
        dir: "report/"
      }
    },
    makeReport: {
      src: "report/*.json",
      options: {
        type: "lcov",
        dir: "test",
        print: "detail"
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-qunit");
  grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-istanbul");

  grunt.registerTask("default", ["instrument", "connect", "qunit", "storeCoverage"/*, "makeReport"*/]);

};
```

testable.js

```
function runable ()
{
  return true;
};
```

test1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>QUnit Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="qunit.css">
</head>
<body>
  <script src="qunit.js"></script>
  <script src="testable.js"></script>
  <script>
    QUnit.test("hello test", function (assert)
    {
      assert.ok(runable());
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything works, qunit runs and the one assert does run on the instrumented file and succeeds. But when it hits the storeCoverage task it fails. Am I doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated of course.

Comment: got the same problem here. Did you ever find a solution??

Comment: I also have the same issue with a similar configuration.  Any updates greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using the [Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/taichi/grunt-istanbul/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) from the `grunt-istanbul` project.

Their documentation indicates that the `reloadTasks` is not required, but for me it actually was.  The `clean` task they do also assists to tidy up.  Also noted in their docs, you can set an ENV variable, rather than using the `env` task.

Try adding these to your `Gruntfile.js`:

```
env: {
  coverage: {
    APP_DIR_FOR_CODE_COVERAGE: rootPath + 'path/to/instrument'
  }
},

clean: ['path/to/coverage'],

reloadTasks: {
  rootPath: 'path/to/instrument'
},
```

My task looks like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('cover',[
  'env:coverage',
  'clean',
  'instrument',
  'reloadTasks',
  'connect',
  'qunit',
  'storeCoverage',
  'makeReport'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little old, but it might help someone else.

To solve this issue, I needed to point my test code to the instrumented code otherwise the original one.

See the example:

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    env: {
        coverage: {
            APP_DIR_FOR_CODE_COVERAGE: '../test/coverage/instrument/lib/'
        }
    },
    clean: {
        coverage: {
            src: ['test/coverage/']
        }
    },
    instrument: {
        files: 'lib/*.js',
        options: {
            lazy: true,
            basePath: 'test/coverage/instrument/'
        }
    },
    mochaTest: {
        test: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec'
            },
            src: ['test/**/*test.js']
        }
    },
    storeCoverage: {
        options: {
            dir: 'test/coverage/reports'
        }
    },
    makeReport: {
        src: 'test/coverage/reports/**/*.json',
        options: {
            type: 'lcov',
            dir: 'test/coverage/reports',
            print: 'detail'
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha-test');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-istanbul');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-env');

grunt.registerTask('test', 'mochaTest');
grunt.registerTask('coverage', ['env:coverage', 'clean', 'instrument', 'mochaTest', 'storeCoverage', 'makeReport']);};
```

In you test code, point to the instrumented ones.

As described in the [grunt-istanbul site](https://github.com/taichi/grunt-istanbul), you can create a requireHelper file.

```
module.exports = function (path) {
    return require((process.env.APP_DIR_FOR_CODE_COVERAGE || '../lib/') + path);
  };
```

And use it in your test file.

```
var requireHelper  = require('./require_helper');
var fileToBeTested = requireHelper('file-to-be-tested');

describe('Test', function () {

    it('should do some test', function () {
        expect(1).to.equal(1);
    });

});
```